# Investing in republic.co using a credit card

Tags: credit-card, crowdfunding

The crowdfunding site [Republic.co](http://Republic.co) allows investors to invest in opportunities using a credit card: https://republic.co/help/what-payment-methods-can-i-use-to-fund-my-investment-1

Does anyone know if these are coded as cash advance transactions on a credit card?

**Edit: contacted Republic**

I sent Republic a message about this and got the following response:

*Thanks for reaching out. It should show as a "purchase" and not a "cash advance". Your investment is just a one-time payment. It has a recurring charge tag on your statement but this is so if you adjust your investment up or down during the campaign, we can make a commensurate adjustment.*

Comment: It's likely just a plain charge.  Sure, they would suffer some backs but the whole outfit is shoddy, they wouldn't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

There are limited circumstances (depending on how the company is set up to accept credit cards) where this could be tagged as something other than a normal purchase, and then it's up to your issuing bank to decide how to handle the charges.

Frankly I don't know why you'd *invest using a credit card*.  These are startup companies in most cases, many of them a LONG way away from being anything remotely close to a publicly-traded stock where you could sell your holdings, so you can't rationalize using a credit card by the return you'll get (unless you're going to pay the bill in its entirety, which still invalidates the point of using a credit card in the first place!).

If I had to speculate (*and this is speculation!*), I'd say the reason they let people invest by credit card is to make it easier, for starters.  It lets people make a quick, simple transaction when this should be a carefully thought through decision, because you're essentially throwing your money away with many of these companies simply for the vanity of being able to say you invested in them.

After glancing through the site, I would advise you to be careful about investing, mainly because there are heavy restrictions on what you can do with your shares for 12 months after purchase.  Additionally, there is no liquid market for your shares in many (if not most) of these companies.

As they warn, don't invest any money that would require you "alter your lifestyle", which is another way of saying don't put money in that you can't afford to lose or walk away from.

If you can afford to speculate and put a little bit in a few of these companies, however, it could work out alright, but the odds are long.  The majority of them are pre-revenue.

Comment: If you must invest in the new reg-C etc stuff, just roll over to startengine.com.  I certainly don't recommend it, but the rest are a joke/comic.  At least with startengine, say 1/2 of the mockups are serious.  And they have that well-known "shark" guy on board now which lends a certain seriousness.

Comment: I sent Republic a message about this and got the following response:

Thanks for reaching out. It should show as a "purchase" and not a "cash advance". Your investment is just a one-time payment. It has a recurring charge tag on your statement but this is so if you adjust your investment up or down during the campaign, we can make a commensurate adjustment.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you got an answer!(grin)  I would double-check with your credit card company and ask what they say about it just to settle the matter.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity foir anyone googling here:  **"I think ... these transactions are cash advances"  That is flat wrong.**  (A) it's completely inconceivable a joke outfit like this would get the ability to run cash advances, it's just not even in the ballpark.  (B) it is plain as day that it is a normal "purchase" **and the company has actually verified that by phone!!**.  Please edit the answer to not spread misinformation.

Comment: My answer was posted BEFORE the OP had the conversation with Republic, so you have the benefit of more information than was originally posted.  And the second answer below does a good job of laying out scenarios where this wouldn't be a "normal purchase" and could be transacted as something else.

Answer (score 2):

Everything SRiverNet said about investing is good advice.  However, I think they're most likely to charge your card as a **Security Broker/Dealer** (MCC 6211).  The [Visa document about it](https://usa.visa.com/content/dam/VCOM/download/merchants/visa-merchant-data-standards-manual.pdf) says:

- Merchants classified with this MCC are licensed, in all
  jurisdictions they sell into to buy, sell and broker
  securities, stocks, bonds, commodities, and mutual
  funds.

Depending on what they actually do with the money internally, I could see it being possible that they will charge your card as one of:

- Money Transfer company (MCC 4829)

> Merchants classified with this MCC allow customers
> to transfer funds via an electronic funds transfer / wire
> transfer / remittance (both card-present and cardabsent locations including on the premises of the
> merchant and third-party agents such as casinos,
> truck stops, or check-cashing storefronts) or via an
> original credit transaction (e.g., via Visa Direct or
> Person to Person [P2P] payments).

- Financial Institutions – Merchandise, Services, and Debt Repayment (MCC 6012)

> This MCC must be used by Financial Institutions for
> the purchase of merchandise or services from or the
> repayment of debts to banks, savings and loans,
> thrifts, and credit unions. For example: the purchase
> of checks, other financial products, or promotional
> merchandise, deposits, the funding of an account, the
> purchase or reload of a stored value card, the
> purchase of foreign currency, non-fiat currency (for
> example: cryptocurrency), money orders (a
> negotiable paper based remittance – not a Money
> Transfer), travelers cheques, and loan fees or
> financial counseling service fees. This MCC must also
> be used for the repayment of a debt, loan, or credit
> card balance by a cardholder to the financial
> institution.

- Non-Financial Institutions – Foreign Currency, Non-Fiat Currency (for example: Cryptocurrency), Money Orders (Not Money
  Transfer), Account Funding (not Stored Value Load), Travelers Cheques, and Debt Repayment (MCC 6051)

> This MCC must be used for the funding of an account
> (excluding prepaid card loads), the purchase of
> foreign currency, non-fiat currency (for example:
> cryptocurrency), money orders, or travelers cheques
> that occurs at non-Financial Institutions such as
> currency exchanges or money order (a negotiable
> paper based remittance – not a Money Transfer)
> merchants.

Whether any of those count as a cash advance for purposes of your specific card, I don't know.

Comment: Nice work, @Bobson!  All you said is spot on, and I still hold it will likely be a cash advance because that's what it really is in most respects.  One probable reason is to prevent a charge dispute.  Imagine letting someone charge a stock trade that goes the wrong way and then have them dispute that charge.  I'm upvoting your answer because of how thorough you were, by the way!

Comment: @SRiverNet - Yeah, the chargeback problem is definitely something they're going to have to deal with.  It really depends what Republic.co does with the money behind the scenes.  If it goes directly to the company being invested in, that's different from if it goes to buy a share in a pool that Republic.co maintains, for example.  But they may also be counting on the "Know your customer" information they collect to defend themselves against any chargebacks.

Comment: Yeah, good luck with that. (grin)  Amex is nothing nice on chargebacks when it comes to how they deal with merchants.

Comment: There's not a chance "republic.co" would achieve broker/dealer with Visa !

Comment: I sent Republic a message about this and got the following response: Thanks for reaching out. It should show as a "purchase" and not a "cash advance". Your investment is just a one-time payment. It has a recurring charge tag on your statement but this is so if you adjust your investment up or down during the campaign, we can make a commensurate adjustment. Thoughts?

Comment: @karancan - You can ask about MCC code specifically (I'm tempted to do so myself), but that makes perfect sense to me.  Visa and MC have rules about when and how a merchant is allowed to initiate a transaction using previously-provided card data, and this sounds like it falls into the bucket of "Unscheduled card-on-file merchant-initiated transaction", where the merchant charges your card automatically but not regularly (such as when your EZPass balance gets low).  That's treated very similarly to recurring charges.

Comment: ... It doesn't say anything about what type of merchant they're charging you as, but it does **imply** that behind the scenes you have a cash-like account with them which is then used to make other purchases (the actual investments) and they charge you to refill that account whenever it goes below $0 (i.e. you bought something).  It's a bit oddball, but plausible.  It'd also imply that "investments" are just them moving money around internally, and if the transaction is contested and chargedback, they'd just reclaim those shares.  But that's just inference on my part - I may be way off.

Comment: @Fattie - Most merchants don't deal with Visa directly.  They sign up with a merchant bank and send them the transactions, and the bank sends them to Visa/MC/Amex/etc. It's the bank's responsibility to ensure the merchant is correctly documented and classified and is following all appropriate mandates for whatever industry they're in.

Comment: @Bobson - I owned a card processing company

Comment: @karancan - exactly **as I already said, at the extreme top of the page, in the first comment, it is simply totally unconceivable that a joke outfit like this would get a broker "rating" from Visa**.  it is Totally Inconceivable.  as I already explained, it's a normal charge. comic businesses like this work on the basis that they will get quite a few charge backs, but they just count it as a cost.  when you're running a scam you don't care if 1/4 of the cash gets away from you.  Also to cut to the XY problem and make it simple, for God's sake **DON'T GIVE THESE PEOPLE ANY OF YOUR MONEY**

Comment: as I already said, if you *must* take a chance on the new Reg funding schemes, for now the only non-scam outfit is startengine.  In no way do I endorse them (my estimate is that "only" 50% of the projects there are comic jokes - companies based on "a photoshop rendering") but again if you are just totally compelled to invest in one of these, as of writing only startengine rises above being "utterly useless projects / plain scams", plus importantly they now have that famous investor guy ("shark" or whatever) associated with them, which keeps them slightly more honest.  Best of luck!